# Return a code if there is no matching record

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to write a function in PL/SQL that takes one argument, `pname`, and returns how many times `pname` (players name) has played at his favourite stadium. This part works mostly as intended. My issue is rather with the error handling I'm trying to add in. i.e

- If `pname` doesn't exist in players.name then return -2
- If `pname` doesn't exist in favstadiums.player then return -1

This is what I have (the parts that have been converted to comments is what I'm trying to figure out):

```
create or replace function favS(pname varchar2) return number
as
    fav_stadium_count number;
    vplayername varchar(100);
begin
    select sum(case when favstadiums.stadium = matches.stadium then 1 else 0 end),
    players.name into fav_stadium_count, vplayername
    from favstadiums
    full outer join players
    on favstadiums.player = players.name
    full outer join matches
    on favstadiums.stadium = matches.stadium
    where name = pname
    and players.team in (matches.home, matches.away)
    group by players.name;
    if (fav_stadium_count >= 0) then
        return fav_stadium_count;
    end if;
    -- if (pname not in players.name) then
    --  return -2;
    -- end if;
    -- if (pname not in favstadiums.player) then
    --  return -1;
    -- end if;
end;
```

I've tried storing players.name as variable `vplayername` and using `if (pname not in vplayername) then...` but this returns no value, not `-2`.

Another seperate issue I'm having not related to the error handling is that `fav_stadium_count` will never return a count of 0.

Help would be much appreciated.

**Edit:**

Here is the relational diagram if it helps (I know it looks unusual, but I didn't create it):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a big fan of returning error codes, but it's sometimes useful I guess. If you want to do this you need to know whether it exists in the table, which means you need to *select* it...

If it exists, i.e. it is not null then you have one, if it is null then the player doesn't exist.

As you're selecting on `WHERE players.name = pname` the name in `PLAYERS` will *always* exist. So, this seems a little pointless, equally, I'm not sure why you would want to do all the FULL OUTER JOINs, you should probably have foreign keys to ensure that your data is consistent. Is it possible for someone to enter a player into `FAVSTADIUMS` that doesn't already exist in `PLAYERS`?

```
create or replace function favS(pname varchar2) return number is

    l_fav_stadium_count number;
    l_player_exists players.name%type;
    l_favstadiums_exists favstadiums.player%type;

begin

    select sum(case when favstadiums.stadium = matches.stadium then 1 else 0 end)
         , players.name
         , favstadiums.player
      into l_fav_stadium_count, l_player_exists, l_favstadiums_exists
      from favstadiums
      full outer join players
        on favstadiums.player = players.name
      full outer join matches
        on favstadiums.stadium = matches.stadium
     where name = pname
       and players.team in (matches.home, matches.away)
     group by players.name
            , favstadiums.player;

    if l_fav_stadium_count >= 0 then
        return l_fav_stadium_count;
    elsif l_player_exists is null then
        return -2;
    elsif l_favstadiums_exists is null then
        return -1;
    end if;

end;
/
```

As you're joining on the players name there should be no problem including an extra one in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Thanks I tried this but i'm still having issues. Firstly, I think `favstadiums.name` should be `favstadiums.player` right? (as favstadiums.name is not a column, so I get an error using this). Also it still won't return any values for the error handling.

Comment: To your first point, yes :-); I've corrected it and updated my answer. I don't understand what you mean by "this won't return any values for the error handling" though. You're _not_ error handling firstly, you won't receive any errors with this code. It certainly won't return any values for `players.name` as this will always exist as this is what you're selecting on.

Answer (score 0):

Your query doesn't look right, as it tries too many things at once.

The players.name is given as pname therefore you don't need to return it from the query. You want the result for only one player, therefore you don't need to group on players.name.

First use separate queries to check if pname is a valid player then to check if it is connected with a stadium. Return the negative values here if the checks fail.

Then write a query that stores only the sum(...) for the given player in fav_statium_count. There are only two possible results for such a query: fav_statdim_count is null if there are no results for the player, or it is a count from 0.

Answer (score 0):

If your base query is right, you can test for the two conditions afterwards, using separate queries:

```
declare cnt number;

. . .

select count(*) into cnt from players where players.name = pname;

if cnt = 0 then
    return -2;

select count(*) into cnt from fav_stadiums where fs.player = pname;

if cnt = 0 then
    return -1;
```